# CodeInsight and virtual/dynamic methods

Tags: delphi, overriding

I am using Delphi 2007 SP3 to develop an application. to override a method I usually using CodeInsight auto completion feature in class declaration to show lists of files that can be overridden from the parent class. Delphi was used to show to me the list of methods with "override" appended to the end of these method. However lately, Delphi CodeInsight stopped to show to me these methods available to override. For example, each TForm is inherited from TCustomForm if you press Ctrl+Space in class declaration then a list of methods that can be overriden in TForm from TCustomForm is shown usually but this does not happen to me. Anyone face such situation.

Comment: There is an error in your code, or the inheritance may be too deep (you may not have enough memory for it)

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @beerwin - I have the same problem with D2007, even on simple class hierarchies, on a machine with 3GB of ram, so it **may** not be his code. It won't even show base TForm virtual methods like DoShow. It works fine on Delphi 6

Comment: Yes, this problem  does not occur with Delphi 6/7 as I used them before. This only occurs with Delphi 2007 with Update 3. My PC has 4 GB of RAM and I don't think that memory is a problem or the code. Maybe the problem lies in a component or add-in as I installed Castalia but because the debugger acted strangely, I removed it and since then this problem occurred but I am not sure that Castalia is the problem as I don't remember if CodeInsight has this problem before removing Castalia.